# CDC Source Issue in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis-2012

I'm using CDC Source component in one of my packages and was getting CDC Timeout error. After searching for a solution, I changed the property Command Timeout from 30 to 0 (Zero).

Now, to retrieve 300K records it's taking more than 30 minutes. How can I reduce that time?

Comment: Please don't use the word lakh. Nobody outside India knows what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Previously we were using CDC Source component with Net CDC processing mode, then changed to All.Records are retrieved faster than expected.